# Have separate Dequeue Count for function in same function app

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app

I have a function app with multiple functions that triggers on storage queues. If af function throws an exception you can configure it to retry in the host file by setting maxDequeueCount to the numbers of times you would like to retry. But what if you different behaviors for different functions? So some would not put anything in the poison queue and some would retry 3 times? I know I could just catch the exception, but then it is displayed in the monitor view as succeeded. Is there any attributes I could use to differentiate or other approaches? Or can it only be solved with multiple function apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there are only a few settings(like `log level`) can be specified per function in azure functions.

For `maxDequeueCount`, it's not supported. Here is [an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5972#issuecomment-776130374) regarding this. And for now, you can only do it with multiple function apps.